# Resolve binding without instatiating object in Ninject

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject

I have interface (e.g. `IMyInterface`). I need to get of which type object will be created if I call `kernel.Get<IMyInterface>()`. Not the instance of `IMyInterface` but the type of instance without creating instance itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ninject doesn't have this functionality. From a Ninject `IKernel` (like `StandardKernel`) you can call `GetBindings(Type)` but Ninject uses a provider model, so the binding's provider has to be invoked to view the result.

I would suggest creating a custom meta-service to mappings of services to implementations, if this functionality really needs to be dynamic.